# Why snapshot speed up Application startup?

Tags: virtual-machine, snapshot

I have three questions.

1. Why Snapshot speeds up Application startup?
2. If a Snapshot is good for application startup, why is there no large-scale use in other popular VMs?
3. Are there any side effects of Snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Snapshot speed up Application startup?

It actually speeds up the boot of the emulator by saving a snapshot of its RAM once it has booted, and restoring from that snapshot on future uses. That way, it doesn't have to run the boot process (which is slow, because it's emulated) every time you start the emulator.

> If a snapshot is good for application to start up, Why is there no large-scale use in other popular VMs

When you make a snapshot, the original virtual disk is frozen and a snapshot file is created. From that moment on, all the changes that would otherwise be made to your virtual disk, are written to the snapshot file.

If you are happy with the new situation, you can commit the snapshot. All your changes will then be applied to your original virtual disk and the snapshot file can be deleted.

Otherwise, you can roll back your system to the state it was when you made the snapshot.

It is also possible to make another snapshot when you already have a snapshot. The original snapshot will then be frozen and all the changes go to the second snapshot file. You can continue this to create several roll-back points in history (as you already mentioned).

> Are there any side effects of Snapshot?

Over time, the snapshot file will grow, especially when you make a lot of changes to your system, like installing new software packages or deleting a large number of files. If you make several Snapshot(s), they can even become bigger than the original disk.

Each snapshot can technically grow to the same size as the original virtual hard drive, as the snapshot can represent the changes to every block of the virtual hard drive if needed; ex: 1 snapshot of a 100GB VM could mean up to approx 200GB of storage needed, 2 snapshots of 100GB VM could mean approx up to 300GB, 3 snapshots of 100GB approx up to 400GB… As you can see the possible storage can add up quickly.

> **It can even get worse**

When removing a snapshot and committing it back to the original virtual hard drive, the hyper-visor basically creates another snapshot to run on (usually this is all done in the background without the users knowledge), then the snapshots difference disk is committed to another snapshots difference disk, or in case there is only one snapshot left, it is then committed to the original virtual hard drive file. Once committed background snapshot is then committed back to the virtual hard drive file. The amount of time it takes to commit all snapshots back to the original hard drive file depends on how many block changes need to be applied to the virtual hard drive.

Plus don’t forget the I/O performance hits; the data from the snapshot(s) difference disks has to eventually be written to the main virtual hard drive of the VM during a commit; your reading data on one file in a directory, writing it all to another file, while a temp file is being written too, all in the same directory; you are going to have an I/O performance hit of some sort. This means all running VMs on that host will have some form of performance hit. Makes sense right?

*So some guidelines:*

1. RTM – read the manual, best practices, and follow them.
2. VM snapshots are not a backup, EVER! They are just one step in the
   backup & testing procedures.
3. Running on snapshots for an extended amount of time is a bad idea,
   don’t do it!
4. Hardware fails at the worst time; so never do rules 1 – 3.
5. Do not over commit your storage, remember this: VM allocated storage
   X number of snapshots = approx theoretical total size of VM.